# Is there any limit to receive response service from windows Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Is there any limit to send/receive an API response service from windows Azure Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't any limit to send/receive an API response from Azure VM. The VM create in Azure, it works as a server same as a on-premises server.
About the Azure VMs limits, refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits).

The Azure VM's performance according to different [VM size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-sizes).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

No, I think there isn't any limit as such. VMs are billed on capacity and no of hours run.

Answer (score 0):

No limit, but you do need to pay for bandwidth after a certain point. Check here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/.

The first 5 Gigabytes per month of outbound traffic are **free**.

After that you have to start paying something. Your VM will usually cost way more than the bandwidth (license, VM size, storage).